# What is the syntax for describing how to call a command?

Tags: syntax, standards

If I have this command:

```
do_something
```

And requires 2 arguments `argument_1` `argument_2`

`argument_1` can be anything
`argument_2` only can be `true` or `false`

A non-required third argument can be added `argument_3`

What is the standard to describe a script calling template?

I remember to have read somewhere about the different meanings of `<>` and `[]` and `{}`. For example:

- `<>` mean required
- `[]` mean non-required
- `{}` contains a list of possible values

So for my example it will be

```
do_someting <argument_1> {true,false} [argument_3]
```

But I don't find any place that is confirming this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I would write the following:

`do_someting argument_1 {true|false} [argument_3]`

I think mendatory arguments don't need any kind of braces, it looks clearer like that. Furthermore, the pipe feels more standard to represent an "or" statement.

I am not aware of such standard, but you can have a look at [Google recommendations](https://developers.google.com/style/code-syntax) or [docopt](http://docopt.org/) for example. Also, here is a [POSIX document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) which may interest you.